# Can I see edits to my comments?

Tags: support, comments, edits

Someone edited [a comment that I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480814/what-java-rest-framework-to-use-with-app-engine-and-android-for-students/5480819#5480819).  Is there a way for me to see what change was made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no edit history on comments.

AFAIK only diamond moderators can edit other people's comments, and such editing is rare; it is only done if there is rude or offensive content in the comment, or occasionally for a minor spelling or grammatical fix.

Comment: [Correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757): *Moderators can edit any comments at any time. This action is logged and visible in that moderator's user history to other moderators. It will also show the pencil icon.  Also, I am a princess on a pretty pony.*

Comment: I wish I knew why mine was edited, but I'll survive without having my curiosity satisfied.  (For all I know, I was the one who edited it and forgot having done so.  It was a long night spent brushing and brading my unicorn's tail.  Pretty pretty tail hair.)