# Is there a way to view edits made to comments to a reply?

Tags: support, comments, edits

Is there any way to view edits made to comments to a reply ? For example if someone modify one of their comments, can the original be seen ?

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Comment: Also see [Can I see edits to my comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85534)

Comment: Also see [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)

Comment: In conclusion, you can only see *if* a comment has been edited. If a comment has been edited, you can see how many edits were made. This comment was edited, so there is a pencil icon next to it. You can mouse over that icon to see a tooltip telling you how many times it was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work):

> Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.

You can see that a comment has been edited (a pencil icon [image: pencil icon] is added), and you can see how many times a comment has been edited (mouse over the pencil, a tooltip will show the edit count if edited more than once).

However, due to their disposable nature, no editing history is visible<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1 <sub>There is one exception to this: if a moderator edits a comment, the fact that they did is visible to other moderators in the editing moderator user history. This information is never available to regular users.</sub></sup>